# Output when I read in a txt.file with numbers in each line

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I want to read the numbers from the following text file:

```
5
8
-2
11
3
-5
2
10
```

This is my java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        InputStream inStream = null;
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            String userInput = bufferedReader.readLine();
            inStream = new FileInputStream(userInput);
            BufferedReader readerFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

            while(readerFile.ready()) {
//                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine()));
                int number = Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine());
                arrayList.add(number);
            }
            System.out.println("Foreach print:");

            for(int number:arrayList) {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        finally {
            bufferedReader.close();
            inStream.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Like this the code works perfectly.
What I don`t understand is when I use the line `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine()));` as part of my code in order to see what he reads. The rest remains unchanged. I get this result:

[image]

Why do I get this result? I`m totally confused. Thx in advance!

Greetings from Vienna/Austria

Fabian

Comment: where are you adding this print statement? if you are keeping the first code that reads the line and add this with it,, then that code will read a line and this print statement will read the other.. so you will skip one each time

Comment: Use `System.out.println(number)`  to avoid reading an additional line .

Comment: @maha Im adding this print statement System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine())); in the while loop

Comment: @Arnaud can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call readerFile.readLine() it reads one line.  So when you uncomment the line you have commented, then half the lines are being eaten by that code and half are being eaten by the line after it.

```
while(readerFile.ready()) {
    String line = readerFile.readLine();
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line));
    int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
    arrayList.add(number);
}
```

would fix it.  Or better still:

```
while(readerFile.ready()) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine());
    System.out.println(number);
    arrayList.add(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what I understand is that you are calling `readLine` twice.. one with and one without printing.

to avoid this, use the following code:

```
while(readerFile.ready()) {
   int number = Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine());
   System.out.println(number);
   arrayList.add(number);
}
```

Comment: Ahh so he basically jumps tp the next line? That makes sense.

Comment: exactly! the scanner already read the line when printing it.. so reading again will go to the next one

Answer (score 1):

That output occurs because, when you uncomment the `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine()))` line, you are reading **two lines at a time** within the `while` loop.

As suggested, read the number to a variable and then add this variable to the list and print it:

```
while(readerFile.ready()) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine());
    arrayList.add(number);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `readerFile.readLine()`, because each time when you call **readerFile.readLine()**, it will point to next line. You are just utilizing a reference when you call it eachtime. for fixing the above code. Change the code as follows.

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(readerFile.readLine());    
System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

readerFile.readLine()

1. return String - the currenct line is pointing at
2. and then pointing to then next line
   (working same has iterator interface)

which means that calling .readLine() twice will make you skip the line - 1, 3, 5 .....and you will get only the lines 2, 4, 6 ....
(if we start counting from 1)

i would recomnd this:

```
        String sCurrentLine;

       while ((sCurrentLine = readerFile.readLine()) != null) {
               int number = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);
               System.out.println(number);
               arrayList.add(number);
            }
```